# Run function multiple times

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

i am developing in lightning and i have a function in controller

```
copyTrans : function (cmp, event, helper) {
    helper.copyTransaction(cmp, event);
    console.log('copy in controller');
}
```

What i want is, to put there some kind of parameter, which will let me select, how many times i want to call this function.

For example: I have a form in component, where i can input number and than submit it. After sumbit, the function from controller will be called N times, same as input on the front end component.

Hope thats understandable.
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by defining an integer on your component, then defining a loop in your controller that calls N times. Just make sure your attribute is referenced in an input field. Here is my code:

**runN.cmp**

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="num" type="Integer" default="1"/>

    <div class="slds-p-around--medium">
        <lightning:input class="slds-p-bottom--small" type="number" label="Enter N" value="{!v.num}" step="1"/>
        <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Run" title="Run" onclick="{!c.handleClick}"/>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

**runNController.js**

```
({
    handleClick : function(component, event, helper) {
        var n = component.get("v.num");
        for (var i=1; i<=n; i++) {
            console.log('Copy in controller: ' + i);
        }
    }
})
```

[image: Example of code running in app container]